# Как отслеживает изменния шаблонизатор Vue.js из внутри?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, шаблоны

Как работают интерактивные переменные и методы в template `vue.js`? Интересный сам процесс отслеживания изменения переменных. Весома ли нагрузка на клиента, в случае множества переменных(например, реализация большой таблички подобно Excel).

Мои догадки в том, что фреймворк хранит в себе клон объектов и в цикле (например с помощью `setInterval`, проверяет изменения. В случае не соотвествия перерисовывает(собирает) `html`.

Comment: исходники же открыты, можно посмотреть и даже отлаживать сразу https://github.com/vuejs/vue

Comment: Никаких таймеров все основано на сеттерах геттерах + виртуальный DOM.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, забыл за них... А интересно рендерится полностью template или частями

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1006906/256824